# Camera Zoom when Player Died and Focus the player position c#

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, zooming

i am developing endless game . when player dies then **camera zoom and focus on player position.** i try and almost done. To zoom the camera i use `orthographicSize` and focus to the player i use `transform.LookAt()` that focus the player position when player dies.but the problem is **when camera Zoom the scene then entire scene gets rotate.** i have created **CameraScript** and attached to the  **maincamera** .

```
[SerializeField]
private Camera gameCam;

[SerializeField]
private Transform[] target;

IEnumerator ZoomIn(){

    while (gameCam.orthographicSize > 3) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
        transform.LookAt (target [index]);
        gameCam.orthographicSize -= 0.1f;
    }

}

public void ZoomCam(){

    StartCoroutine (ZoomIn ());

}
```

Help me to that Script if any mistake..Thanks..

Comment: Hmmm..."when camera Zoom the scene then entire scene gets rotate" - could you clarify what you mean by that? Perhaps with more details, and a GIF or before/after screenshot? A visual aid might be helpful in this situation.

Comment: its mean that when the camera focus to the player when dies then entire scene rotate, sorry not allowed to upload Game Screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening because you're not setting the `worldUp` parameter when you're calling `transform.LookAt(...)`.

I suggest using the camera's own current up vector as that parameter, i.e.

```
transform.LookAt (target [index], transform.up);
```

I hope that helps!

**EDIT:**
Of course, this would only work if your camera is originally oriented as you intend it to be. Else, you'll have to use the vector you choose as the second parameter there.

Comment: @DarshanSoni I suggest you look at the [docs for Transform.Lookat() here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html). The second parameter specifies the direction of the camera's up vector, therefore orienting it exactly the way you want it. All the best!

Comment: thanks @andeart  but i have try this. use Vector3.up & all others as a 2nd parameter in Lookat() but its not work there is no effect when i run game.